# sort by column header in vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, lodash

I'm using Vue 2.x and according to this [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-orderBy-Filter) - the `orderby` directive is no longer available.

I'd prefer not to have to have another JS library, however if I can get lodash to work then I guess that would be ok.  I tried several other attempts ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript),[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)) of JS sorting which didn't seem to work at all.

However, I want to be able to click on a table header value and do the sort based off of that value.

My `rowData` array is populated via a database call and it looks something like this:

```
rowData:Array[79]
 0:Object
  ActiveDate:"06/25/2018"
  CountryId:10
  ExportedDate:""
  ExportedStatus:"0"
  Id:1751
  ItemType:"Condition Types"
  LogId:72843
  ModifiedDate:"06/25/2018"
  Name:"GenericNameGoesHere"
  ParentTable:"tableNameGoesHere"
  Region:"Home Office"
  Type:"CI"
  TypeId:123
  selectedExport:false
```

What I'm trying to do to start is to order by the **ItemType** property.  In `rowData` I have multiple ItemType values (**Condition Types**, **Medical Reference**, **Synonyms**, **References** etc).

In my table header I have the following:

```
v-on:click="sortBy('ItemType')"
```

This is what I have so far (sortKey is not being used yet as ItemType is hardcoded):

```
sortBy: function (sortKey) {
    var vm = this;
    _.orderBy(vm.rowData, ['ItemType'], ['asc']);
},
```

**At this point in time, I am NOT seeing any sorting.  To be honest, I'm not sure if it is my Vue code or the lodash code.**

Let me know if you need to see more of my array or any other code.  I'd really like to be able to sort by column head (currently there are 7 other headers that I need to sort by).

**Edit:**

I've also tried this (which didn't change anything):

```
return _.orderBy(vm.rowData, ['ItemType']);
```

Comment: Try adding `return` to your `sortBy` function.

Comment: @HassanImam - that did not work.  I also took at the ['asc'] and that did not work either.

Comment: Please add a working snippet.

Comment: @HassanImam - I will have to put something together.  But the array is populated dynamically, so it won't be the same as coming from a DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_.orderBy` does not mutate the array in place, it returns a new array, so `vm.rowData` itself is not sorted and Vue doesn't react to any changes (since there were none). Even if `_.orderBy` did mutate the array in place Vue still wouldn't be able to track the changes because it can't see array accesses (one of Vue's reactivity pitfalls, docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats). In this situation what you need to do is:

```
sortBy: function (sortKey) {
    let vm = this;
    vm.$set(vm, 'rowData', _.orderBy(vm.rowData, ['ItemType'], ['asc']);
},
```

And that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way?

```
@click="sortBy('ItemType')"

sortBy (key) {
  this.rowData = _.orderBy(this.rowData, key, 'asc')
},
```